# File Downloadin in android with service?

Tags: android-emulator

When i downloadin a file from Web in android, then i want to show progress bar in notification area of status bar through service, but i can not able to do this. how can i do it. I am not able to pass the file length in service. Please help me.
thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

Check the AsyncTask. This can help you implement your UI thread without having problem with background threads. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html